# Pandas date formatting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below two functions :

```
def create_base_df(start_date, end_date):
    base_df = pd.DataFrame({"dt": pd.date_range(start_date, end_date)})
    base_df["dt_num_key"] = base_df.dt.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strftime(x, "%Y%m%d")).astype(int)
    base_df["cal_yr_nkey"] = base_df.dt.dt.strftime("%Y")
    base_df["cal_mon_ofyr_nkey"] = base_df.dt.dt.strftime("%m")
    base_df["cal_qtr_ofyr_nkey"] = base_df.dt.dt.quarter.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.rjust(2, '0'))
    base_df["cal_wk_ofyr_nkey"] = base_df.dt.dt.week.astype(str)

    return base_df

def month_operations(df):
    df["cal_mon_nm"] = df.dt.dt.strftime("%B")
    df["cal_mon_shrt_nm"] = df.dt.dt.strftime("%b")
    df["cal_yr_mon_nkey"] = df["cal_yr_nkey"] + df["cal_mon_ofyr_nkey"]
    df["mon_seq_id"] = df.cal_yr_mon_nkey.sort_values().reset_index()     ["cal_yr_mon_nkey"].rank(method='dense').astype(int)
    df["dt_frst_dayof_mon"] = df.dt.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime(x.year, x.month, 1))
    df["dt_frst_dayof_mon_nkey"] =   df["dt_frst_dayof_mon"].dt.strftime("%Y%m%d")
    df["dt_lst_dayof_mon"] = df["dt_frst_dayof_mon"] + pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(
    months=1) - pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(days=1)
    df["dt_lst_dayof_mon_nkey"] =   df["dt_lst_dayof_mon"].dt.strftime("%Y%m%d")
    df["dt_frst_dayof_lst_mon"] = df["dt_frst_dayof_mon"] - pd.DateOffset(months=1)
    df["dt_frst_dayof_lst_mon_nkey"] = df["dt_frst_dayof_lst_mon"].dt.strftime("%Y%m%d")
    df["dt_lst_mon"] = df.dt - pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months=1)
    df["dt_lst_mon_nkey"] = df["dt_lst_mon"].dt.strftime("%Y%m%d")
    df["dt_lst_yr_lst_mon"] = df.dt_lst_mon - pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)
    df["dt_lst_yr_lst_mon_nkey"] = df["dt_lst_yr_lst_mon"].dt.strftime("%Y%m%d")

    return df
```

The columns dt_lst_yr_lst_mon_nkey, dt_lst_mon_nkey and dt_frst_dayof_lst_mon_nkey are returning values in datetime format ('1899-12-01 00:00:00') and I cant seem to figure out why. All the other *key columns return integers as expected

my main looks like below:

```
base_df = create_base_df(start_date="01/01/1900", end_date="01/12/1900")
month_df = month_operations(base_df)
```

The expected output  : if the value of **dt_lst_yr_lst_mon** is "1900-12-01 00:00:00" then dt_lst_yr_lst_mon_nkey will be "19001201"

Any pointers on where I am going wrong is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide example of expected output.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the feedback have updated the question to show the expected output for one of the columns I am having issues with.

Comment: When I run your code without modifications it returns your expected output.

Comment: Strange, but I keep getting the same date format instead of the integer compatible one. Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: on jupyter notebook using python3 i get the desired output, but my original environment is 2.7 on an EMR cluster.